# Do I need to add a route for each subnet beyond the subnet I've routed to?

Tags: cisco, routing, ipv4

Do I need to add an IP route for all subnets past the subnet I've routed to?
For example, from R1, do I need to set up a route for .64, .112, .128, .80, .144, .160, and .96?

[image: Network Map]

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

In short: yes.

For routing to work all routers must know the routes to all destination. Because keeping all routers correctly configured manually is tedious and error-prone you usually use a routing protocol (OSPF etc) to do that automatically.

Non-routers (PCs etc) need to have a route to a default gateway that will route the packet to its destination.

If the network becomes larger then you usually aggregate routes. So instead of having separate routes for (for example) `10.1.0.0/24`, `10.1.1.0/24`, `10.1.2.0/24` and `10.1.3.0/24` all pointing in the same direction you would aggregate that into one route for `10.1.0.0/22`.

Answer (score 0):

Routing table need to be update accordinglly so that packet that reaches layer3 devices verify routing table to destine packet to destination .

For this reason layer3 devices need to have  routes to every next hops if traffic wants to destine to destionation on next hop networks.